# Children's book from late 60's about an intelligent frog in a size-shifting LEM spaceship

Tags: story-identification, illustrated-story

I read this fully color-illustrated children's book in 1971 in New Delhi, India. It was in English and may have been a UK printing.  I would guess it to be between forty and sixty pages in length. Given the graphics were based on the Apollo space missions, it must have been published within a few years of 1969.

The story was about a caucasian boy (and possibly a girl) who discover in their garden a member of a a space-faring anthropomorphic frog society.  The main frog wore, I believe, a blue pressure suit.  There was an underground lair with a mission control clearly based on NASA of the time.

The LEM ship required no booster.  It traveled great distances by increasing in size through the use of an egg-shaped controller, to several hundred meters or more, thus making the intervening spaces relatively smaller.  The group ends up on Jupiter which is inhabited by human-looking, caucasian giants who are initially hostile, but have their problem solved by the frog and the kid(s).  The frog then returns the kids to their home and gives them candy(bars?) which causes them to forget the adventure had happened (which ticked me off then, and every other time I've seen that trope employed.  I was 5 at the time I read this).

Being 5 at the time, I stayed up in the garden with my (then) four-year old brother all night to try to meet the frog astronaut ourselves.  It would be fun to look at this story again.

Comment: By "LEM" , do you mean a Lunar Excursion Module?

Comment: Yes, the frog's ship's design was like the Lunar Excursion Module.  The flight suits, the command center; everything reflected the visual imagery of the Apollo program.